# Camelcase string to normal string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to change NoOfSAP => No Of SAP? I have trying the replace method but it says undefined.

```js
function unCamlelCase(result) {
  return result.key.replace(/([^A-Z]*)([A-Z]*)([A-Z])([^A-Z]*)/g, '$1 $2 $3$4')
    .replace(/ +/g, ' ');
};
```

How can I change the result key values camel case to normal string?

```js
if (exactMatch) {
  const { ...response } = json[0];
  const result = Object.keys(response).reduce((acc, key) => {let newKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go that way:

```
const camelToWords = (camelCaseWord) => camelCaseWord
  .replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1")
  .replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, "$1");
```

There is also possibility to use existing libraries like lodash:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
console.log(_.startCase('abcDef'));
// result: Abc Def
```

Comment: For the first solution, `NoOfSAP` would be converted to `No Of S A P`

Comment: const newResult = Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(${key})

Comment: How can I return the key and replace the key camelcase to normal string?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following expression with a few helper methods to clean up the output:

```
"NoOfSAP".split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(Boolean).join(' ');
```

This will match all upper case letters followed by one or more lower-case letters and split each chunk into an array. `.filter(Boolean)` is then used to remove any empty strings in the array and `.join` is then used to add spaces between the strings in the array.

See example below:

```js
const getWords = wrd =>
  wrd.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(Boolean).join(' ');
  
console.log(getWords("NoOfSAP")); // No Of SAP
console.log(getWords("ThisIsAWord")); // This Is A Word (notice how it will split individual letters such as A)
console.log(getWords("IAmAHuman")); // I Am A Human
console.log(getWords("JSIsGreat")); // JS Is Great (notice how it understands JS and Is are two seperate words and doesn't give JSI s Great)
```

As per your question about changing the keys in your object to the "uncamelcased" keys you can use `.map` with `Object.keys` to generate your result:

```js
const getWords = wrd =>
  wrd.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(Boolean).join(' ');
  
const obj = {
  "NoOfSAP": 1,
  "NoOfBUN": 2,
  "NoOfBRE": 3,
  "NoOfPEA": 4
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).map(getWords);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195159/discussion-on-answer-by-nick-parsons-camelcase-string-to-normal-string).

Comment: OP didn't have 20 rep, so mods have to manually move to chat.